# Enumeration of proofs

Tags: logic, proof-theory

Is it possible to enumerate *short* proofs of *short* statements, so as to make sure that, say, Goldbach's conjecture doesn't have one of those? How hard would it be? Is it being done?

It's seems likely to me that something interesting might have been missed among *short* proofs. Though I wouldn't know how *short* they'd have to be to make it a computationally feasible endeavor, or how hard it would be to tell which statements are interesting.

Comment: It's possible to enumerate *all* proofs, from shortest to longer, in a given axiomatic system. Of course, you're not going to run across a proof of, say, Gödel's sentence, which is a true but unprovable statement, in this manner.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible to enumerate short proofs -- in fact, to enumerate all proofs in order from shortest to longer.

However, we should not really expect to learn something interesting that way. There are *very many* short proofs of completely trivial or inane truths, such as $2+2=4$ or $\forall x.(2+x=1+x+1)$, and simply getting past them in order to find a proof of something interesting would -- for any *practical* purpose -- take "forever".

The classical way to enumerate all proofs is to enumerate *all possible strings of symbols* and check for each of them whether it happens to be a valid proof or not. This is nice and simple to explain that an enumeration is possible *in principle*, but as a practical procedure for anything it fails horribly. Even with the fastest computers, a proof of something like $2+2=4$ wouldn't emerge within a lifetime.

It's easy to think up some local improvements to this procedure and find a search strategy that would happen across a proof of $2+2=4$ (say, in Peano Arithmetic) in a more or less reasonable time. However, if we up the ante to for example $10+10=20$, that probably still wouldn't happen within any human lifetime -- unless we envisage some kind of *guided search* that aims to prove $10+10=20$ *specifically* rather than just searching through *all* proofs until one for $10+10=20$ pops up.

And by these measures, Goldbach's conjecture is *not* a "short" sentence -- stating it formally would need about 100 symbols, drawn from an alphabet of more than a handful of different symbols. So even if we just enumerate all sentences, without even requiring proof of them, we should expect to wait for not less than $5^{100}$ tries before it comes up. That's much, much longer than the number of nanoseconds in the lifetime of the universe.

Comment: Would it make more sense to start with a set of axioms and inference rules and build from those, so that we don't even have to consider invalid, false and unprovable statements (I assume that's the majority)?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė sure, but you're still exploring a tree with a massive breadth; it's not going to get interesting very quickly.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: That's what I'm alluding to with the "some local improvements" paragraph.